# Image slider is choppy

Tags: javascript, html, css, transform

I have put together a plain javascript/css image slider, started out as just a learning exercise but am now looking to apply it in the real world.  The problem is that the animation is choppy on my desktop (which is a v. high spec gaming rig) - and even worse on a mobile (to the degree it's not really an animation anymore)

You can see it in action here:

www.chrishowie.co.uk/sands/

jsfiddle isolates much of the pertinent code - it's not a "this doesn't work" issue, so hopefully the fiddle gives enough to help optimize it.

http://jsfiddle.net/9aozrxy8/5/

In summary: I have a DIV with 4 images in a row, each image is 100% the width of the page.  I use javascript to translateX (I have tried translate3d as heard this uses GPU, but didnt make much diff) and I set CSS transitions to ease-in the transform.

I also thought that potentially I am just trying to do too much on this site - but then I look at some other sites doing a heck of a lot more and it's smooth as silk.  So I guess I'm missing something.

```
function slideRight() {

if (sliding) {
    return false
};
window.sliding = true;

el = document.getElementById("slider");
cst = getComputedStyle(el);
transformst = cst.transform || cst.webkitTransform || cst.mozTransform;
widthst = cst.width;
widthst = widthst.replace("px", ""); // computed width of slider (7680px)
slidewidth = widthst / 4;

transformst = transformst.replace("matrix(", "");
transformst = transformst.replace(")", "");

transformst = transformst.split(",");
transformst = transformst[4]; // returns current transform in px without unit (px)
if (!transformst) {
    transformst = 0;
}

var activebtn = "sldr" + Math.round((Number(transformst) / (-1 * slidewidth)));
document.getElementById(activebtn).classList.remove("sliderbuttonactive");

if (activebtn != "sldr3") {
    document.getElementById("slider" + Math.round((2 + Number(transformst) / (-1 * slidewidth)))).style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("slider" + Math.round((2 + Number(transformst) / (-1 * slidewidth)))).style.display = "initial";
    document.getElementById("slider").style.transform = "translate3d(" + 25 * ((Number(transformst) / (slidewidth)) - 1) + "%, 0, 0)";
    document.getElementById("slider").style.transform = "-webkit-translate3d(" + 25 * ((Number(transformst) / (slidewidth)) - 1) + "%, 0, 0)";
    document.getElementById("slider").style.transform = "-moz-translate3d(" + 25 * ((Number(transformst) / (slidewidth)) - 1) + "%, 0, 0)";
    document.getElementById("slider").style.transform = "-ms-translate3d(" + 25 * ((Number(transformst) / (slidewidth)) - 1) + "%, 0, 0)";
    document.getElementById("leftslidebtn").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("leftslidebtn").style.display = "block";
}

activebtn = activebtn.replace("sldr", "");
activebtn = "sldr" + (1 + Number(activebtn));

document.getElementById(activebtn).classList.add("sliderbuttonactive");

if (Number(activebtn.replace("sldr", "")) == 3) {
    document.getElementById("rightslidebtn").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("rightslidebtn").style.display = "none";
}

setTimeout(function () {
    window.sliding = false
}, 2000);
```

}

update: still not resolved but on mobile I have made it usable by reducing the image size for small screens and also not displaying images that are off-screen.  Not perfectly smooth but getting there.

Thanks a lot,

C

Comment: Change the setTimeout to a slower speed i.e. 3500, test then decrease value until it is acceptable.

Comment: You slider is pretty broken when it comes to usability anyway. I'd recommend using one that's already made if you put it into production, there are some great ones out there already

Comment: @jeff the Timemout function is just part of my solution to stop the same animation being stacked and resulting in a misaligned slider.  It was choppy before I added it in, so it's not had any impact.

Comment: @ZachSaucier If you have any specific comments about usability I'd welcome them; I started this project to learn and using a pre-made slider won't help with that goal.

Comment: I might have misunderstood something, but the reason your JSFiddle didn't animate for me was the CSS media query declaration setting `transition:none` for viewports narrower than 900px. Take that out, animation is perfectly smooth on Firefox 36 / Win7 / i7 with onboard graphics.

Comment: @Jeremy yes that was an error, I've taken that out now.  The updated fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/9aozrxy8/5/) now doesn't have the media query so you can see the choppy animation properly.  Still choppy on my machine which is i7 + nvidia GTX 780ti.

Comment: You've certainly got a more capable rig than mine. It's still looking fine for me, and the answerer below. I can't think of anything other than browser issues — try with/without hardware acceleration, etc. Also, if you happen to be on Linux, might be a driver issue.

Answer (score 0):

Like Jeremy mentioned, that the "transition" in your JSFiddle caused the problem, it's also causing it on your website.

In your "Main.css" in line 221. Remove the "transition: top ease 2s;" from class .slide

Everything works fine then on Win8.1/Google Chrome/i7